# By what factor does Xindi's subspace vortex tech shorten the distance?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-enterprise, xindi

If my memory serves, the Aquatic ship needed between 10 and 24 hours to travel from the Delphic Expanse to the Sol System via subspace vortex (while helping the Enterprise NX-01 return in the last episode of the Xindi saga). Degra's ship would have taken less time because it was faster.

This means the tech wasn't something which is related to a particular ship. It just shortened the real distance by using a shortcut passage in subspace. That's why a ship was able to enter the vortex created by another ship. And a ship could take better advantage of the subspace vortex than another if it was faster.

I am interested to know about the metrics of subspace vortex tech. By what factor does subspace vortex tech shorten the distance? Is there a number or equation?

AFAIK, *Star Trek: Enterprise* never mentioned it directly. I am looking for answers from an intelligent calculation, or any other work like novels, comics etc.

Comment: I'm pretty certain this is another of those unanswerable questions. I've watched S3 of Enterprise several times now (it's my favourite overall season, although I have episodes I like in others), and I don't believe the story gives us enough to go on. I also expect this is deliberate, frankly -- by the time it was written, the writers were well aware fans would want to know and then hold them to whatever was said or implied...

Answer (score 1):

A user on Memory Alpha called SwordandScales estimated the speed of a subspace vortex at around Warp 9.9941 on the 24th century warp speed scale.

see: http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Subspace_vortex?diff=prev&oldid=905387

Comment: Could you please clarify what approach that user took to estimate (don't need to copy the actual post, just high level)

Comment: That cite was removed because it was described as "notoriously inconsistent"; http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Talk:Subspace_vortex